# Is is possible to load Qt dependant library (dylib) in MonoMac and how to do it?

Tags: c, qt, monodevelop, dylib

I need to create a `dllImport` and some extern functions in a MonoMac project (C#). I added the library to the latest version of MonoDevelop with the `Add Native Reference` option to the project.

I then  added the `dllImport` and the extern functions, I got an Exception saying the Dll was not found.  After running a `System.IO.File.Exists()` on the path I decided to have a method to test loading the lib using Dlfcn.dlopen(), it returned 0.

Then I copied the whole framework directory inside my bin/debug folder (in my project folder) and created native references for each library in the framework. Tried to load libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib, it didn't work.

I started thinking that something could be wrong in the method I was using.  Then I got my sqlLite 3 dylib, copied it and tried the same test and got a pointer with `Dlfcn.dlopen()`.

What am I missing here?  I normally would not like to have the whole Qt baggage in there but the native dylib I have to use, uses this framework.

Is there any way to get a reference to this dylib?